# Managing the bitcoin address gap

Tags: address-generation, address-reuse

We're in the process of setting up bitcoin payments to fund accounts in our system. Using the C# BitcoinLib (https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) to interact with the Bitcoin Daemon.

Our concern is how to manage the Address gap. My understanding is we can only generate 20 unpaid addresses in a row. Each account would have atleast one bitcoin address associated with it. Preferably with the option to generate a new address. So we have to consider the scenario, 20 users generate an address but never pay anything into the address.

How can this problem be dealt with?